# Fluent API configure many to one with composite foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have one lookup table that has a composite key
I have a group of tables that can access it that are built on an abstract class.

I can't seem to get the mapping working, and I have no idea why.  I've looked at a bunch of blog posts and questions here, and I'm still stuck.

Here is the lookup table

```
public partial class ColumnMapping
{
    public string TableName { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

}
```

Here is the mapping for it

```
ToTable("ColumnMap");
HasKey(t => new { t.TableName, t.Id });
Property(t => t.TableName).HasColumnName("TableName");
Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("ID");
Property(t => t.Name).HasColumnName("Name").IsRequired();
Property(t => t.Value).HasColumnName("Value").IsRequired();
```

In the other table I have the property

```
public virtual ColumnMapping ColumnMap { get; set; }
```

[I looked at this post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/JJ591620.aspx)

Which gives something like this

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Course>()  
    .HasRequired(c => c.Department)  
    .WithMany(d => d.Courses) 
    .HasForeignKey(d => new { d.DepartmentID, d.DepartmentName });
```

But that doesn't work.

I can't seem to get a mapping that doesn't cause a compile error.

For example

```
HasRequired(m => m.ColumnMap).WithMany().HasForeignKey(ex => new { tableName, ex.Id });
```

Isn't allowed.

Comment: What is `tableName` supposed to represent in `HasForeignKey`? The key should only contain references to properties on the FK entity.

Comment: @TimRogers, I tried using a variable.  I'm adding it as a property now.  It's the actual table name for the second table, which is static.  But I can add a property that just returns the string.

Comment: Yeah, that's not going to work. I'm pretty sure the property will have to map to a real column. Is there any reason you can't make `Id` unique across the whole of `ColumnMapping` and just use a single column key?

Comment: ah, thanks.  I'll check with the dba

Comment: Is there anyway to cheat, and map the property to a string?

Comment: Nevermind, heard back from the dba.  We're all good.  Thanks for clearing it up.  I couldn't figure out why something so simple was giving me such a hard time.